# Create an azure VM from an image using availability zones and templates

Tags: azure

I am currently deploying some new azure VMs using a template. This template contains a link to a VHD image and uses availability sets.

After having a look at the azure docs, I cannot seem to tell or find out if it's possible to use my current procedure to deploy the VM in a specific zone.

I changed my template to use zones rather than sets but when I use it in Azure CLI I have this error message returned:

"Virtual Machines deployed to an Availability Zone must use managed disks."

I then tried to add the managed disk section to the template without success.

Below there is the pseudocode of the template related to the storage of the VM:

```
"storageProfile": {
          "osDisk": {
             "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
            },
            "osType": "Linux",
            "name": "myName.vhd",
            "createOption": "FromImage",    
            "image": {
              "uri": "myUri.vhd"
            },
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "myVhdImageUri.vhd"
            },              
            "caching": "ReadWrite"
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [convert disk to managed disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks) first. Then you will be able to use it in your template.

Comment: That is true when the VM is already created, I think?

Comment: That's right. If you just have your .vhd stored in blob you can also convert it. Go to the "Disks" blade and create a new managed disk. Choose storage blob as a source and point to the your .vhd. I cannot find an official document for that, but this blog post https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/how-to-create-managed-disks-from-vhd-in-azure/ should guide you well.

Comment: Thanks for that. Once I have it done, in which way should I modify the template to use the managed disk?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure if I can help you there. I don't have much experience in ARM templates. Personally I do use Terraform for infrastructure provisioning. ARM templates are just too complex to maintain. I encourage you to do the same, you will avoid many headaches. ;)

Comment: I got it working :) I just need to better refine the managed disk section but I am there! Thanks a lot for the hint.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. You are welcome. If you are happy with the answer please accept it to help community find easier answer to similar question.